# Unable to scan live hosts in a home network

Tags: nmap

I have been trying to scan live hosts that is connected to my home network using nmap but it keeps on returning the IP address of my router and my personal computer.

I tried using the following commands with `nmap`:

```
$ sudo nmap -sP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24

$ sudo nmap -sP -PT80 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24
```

Both of these commands did return on 2 live hosts, that is my laptop's and router's IP addresses.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you saying there are some other connected devices are not showing up in the NMAP result ?

Comment: In version 2.4 and more, the command has a new form: `-sn` ... refer to nmap page for more info.

Comment: @Dere0405 Yes, I have at least 4 live hosts connected to modem/router of a home network. I am trying to search for those live hosts using a laptop via Wi-Fi connection. My scan only returns my laptop's and router's IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

The `nmap` flag `-sP` is depreciated and is now `-sn`(no port scan.) I am unsure what the `-PT80` is for, are you trying to scan for port 80 or set a timing template? You didn't tell us if you had anything else connected to the network or what exactly your network setup is so I can't really speculate further. In any case try this nmap command instead:

```
$ nmap 192.168.1.1-255 #replace with your own home IP range
```

Comment: -PT80 is the scanning option of devices who are using port 80.

Comment: `-p` is port yes, but `-P` isn't anything and `-T` is timing template which accepts a number between 0 and 5. `-PT80` either doesn't do anything or doesn't work as intended.